# How do approach one to many association in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a forumposts table with the following columns:
id (primary key), categoryId, headline, content.

I have another table, forumcategories, with the following columns:
id (primary key), name

The categoryid column in forumposts corresponds to the id column in forumcategories.

How do I associate the two tables?

Comment: Is it a one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many?

Comment: A forum post has a category. A category can be associated with many forum posts.

Comment: I am trying to perform an association in sequelize.js ORM

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
 let ForumPost = sequelize.define('ForumPost', {/* ... */})
 let ForumCategory = sequelize.define('ForumCategory', {/* ... */})

 ForumCategory.hasMany(ForumPost, {as: 'forumposts'})
```

> OR

```
ForumCategory.hasMany( ForumPost, { as: 'forumposts' } );
ForumPosts.hasOne( ForumCategory );
```

You may refer [Sequelize Associations](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/associations/) for further details.